# Byte string to hex string

Tags: c++, string, hex

I have a string containing 968 binary values 0, 1. I need to convert this into a string containing hex values of every byte group of 8 bits.
eg: '111111111000000110011001' converts to 'ff8199'

This is the C++ code that I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void con(char* buf)
{
   long int longint=0;
   int len=8;
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
      longint+=(buf[len-i-1]-48) * pow(2,i);
   cout<<setbase(16)<<longint;
}
int main()
{
   string buf; cin>>buf; char temp[8]; 
   for(int i=0; i<buf.size(); i+=7)
   { 
     for(int k=i; k<i+8; k++)
       temp[k-i]=buf[k];
     con(temp);
   }  
   return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong with it or help me on how to do this.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn to use a debugger to step through the code and see the exact behaviour (and misbehaviour) for yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a routine debugging task.

Comment: Hmm.. i+=7 ? I would look there.

Comment: http://ideone.com/25qIqe

Comment: drat sorry! ofcourse i+=8

Comment: Should have used `CHAR_BIT` instead. Then you wouldn't have these magic numbers floating about.

Comment: [OT] I think that `(buf[len - i - 1] - '0') << i` is more readable than `(buf[len - i - 1] - 48) * pow(2, i)`

Answer (score 1):

In the outer for loop you have to increment the `i` by 8, not by 7:

`for(int i=0; i<buf.size(); i+=8)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
for(int i=0; i<buf.size(); i+=7)
```

7 is wrong here. As you are jumping 8 steps at once so it would be 8 instead of 7.